# Index of first distinct character between two strings using a recursive method

Tags: java, string, recursion

I need to find the index of the first distinct character between two strings using a recursive method.

Examples with expected outputs:

> rFirstDistinctPlace("Little parcels", "Little pretzels") -> 8
>
> rFirstDistinctPlace("Gold shadow", "gold shadow") -> 0
>
> rFirstDistinctPlace("gold", "golda") -> 4
>
> rFirstDistinctPlace("gold","gold") -> -1

**Note:**
I can't use the .equals() function

The thing I'm struggling with is that I need to return -1 if the strings are equal, otherwise it works fine.

Here's my code:

```
    public static int rFirstDistinctPlace (String s1, String s2) {  
    if (smallestString(s1,s2).length()==0){
            return 0;
    }
    if(s1.charAt(0)!=s2.charAt(0))
        return rFirstDistinctPlace(s1.substring(0,0),s2.substring(0,0));

    return 1+rFirstDistinctPlace(s1.substring(1),s2.substring(1));

}
```

This is the helper method `smallestString`:

```
    public static String smallestString (String s1, String s2){
    if(s1.length()>s2.length()){
        return s2;
    }
    else if (s2.length()>s1.length()){
        return s1;
    }
    else
        return s1;
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Recursive Solution:**

- If the two strings are empty, this means they are equal, return `-1`
- Else if one of them is empty or the first characters don't match, return `0`
- Else recur with the substrings, if the result is `-1`, return it, else return it plus `1`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(rFirstDistinctPlace("Little parcels", "Little pretzels")); //8
    System.out.println(rFirstDistinctPlace("Gold shadow", "gold shadow")); //0
    System.out.println(rFirstDistinctPlace("gold", "golda")); //4
    System.out.println(rFirstDistinctPlace("gold","gold")); //-1
}
public static int rFirstDistinctPlace (String s1, String s2) {
    if(s1.isEmpty() && s2.isEmpty()) return -1;
    else if (s1.isEmpty() || s2.isEmpty() || s1.charAt(0) != s2.charAt(0)) return 0; 
    int index = rFirstDistinctPlace(s1.substring(1), s2.substring(1));
    return index == -1 ? index : 1 + index;
}
```

**Iterative Solution:**

- Iterate over the two strings using a `for-loop` until it reaches the end of one of them

  - If the characters of the two strings at the current `index` are different, return `i`
- At the end, if the two strings have different `lengths`, return `i`, else return `-1`

```
public static int rFirstDistinctPlace (String s1, String s2) {
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < s1.length() && i < s2.length(); i++) {
        if(s1.charAt(i) != s2.charAt(i)) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return s1.length() != s2.length() ? i : -1;
}
```

Comment: What would be the best way to write this function iteratively?

Comment: @itailitai I added a possible iterative solution to the answer

Comment: Amazing. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

It's not so complex.

1. Return `-1` if the strings are equal.
2. Return `0` if the length of one of the strings is `0` or if their first characters do not match.
3. Otherwise, return `1 + rFirstDistinctPlace(s1.substring(1), s2.substring(1))`.

**Demo:**

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(rFirstDistinctPlace("Little parcels", "Little pretzels")); // 8
        System.out.println(rFirstDistinctPlace("Gold shadow", "gold shadow"));// 0
        System.out.println(rFirstDistinctPlace("gold", "golda"));// 4
        System.out.println(rFirstDistinctPlace("gold", "gold"));// -1
    }

    public static int rFirstDistinctPlace(String s1, String s2) {
        if (Objects.equals(s1, s2))
            return -1;

        if (s1.length() == 0 || s2.length() == 0 || s1.charAt(0) != s2.charAt(0))
            return 0;

        return 1 + rFirstDistinctPlace(s1.substring(1), s2.substring(1));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
8
0
4
-1
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not allowed to use .equals()